# Installation problem with python-software-properties

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, dependencies

I need to install the last version of node.js but my system has in repository older version. I need to add new ppa source. I followed [this](http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/) tutorial

**Question** - when I install "python-software-properties" package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

program "add-apt-repository" is not installed (nor apt-add-repository):

```
root@vm7590:~# add-apt-repository
The program 'add-apt-repository' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install python-software-properties
```

and

```
root@vm7590:~# apt-add-repository
The program 'apt-add-repository' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install python-software-properties
```

but program "python-software-properties" is already installed.

```
root@vm7590:~# sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo: unable to resolve host vm7590
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Is there some another method hot to add a ppa source?

My system is as follows:

```
root@vm7590:~# uname -a
Linux vm7590 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you haven't got this worked out yet I'd recommend just removing the distro node.js completely and building from source in /usr/local.  I don't think anything will depend on the package being installed as node can manage its own packages anyway.

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands: `apt-cache policy python-software-properties`, `ls -l /usr/bin/apt-add-repository`, `file /usr/bin/apt-add-repository`, `sudo 'echo "$PATH"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the error message when running `apt-add-repository` if that package is installed but the command is not found.

First check if `/usr/bin/apt-add-repository` exists or you can run:

```
dpkg -L python-software-properties | xargs ls -d > /dev/null
```

to see if any of the file from `python-software-properties` are missing.

If there files missing try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties
```

(you can run this without first testing as well).

If `/usr/bin/apt-add-repository` exists, then make sure it is executable and the `/usr/bin` is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Program `apt-add-repository` doesn't exist in my system (I tried `whereis` command, and doesn't exist in `/usr/bin too`), `python-software-properties` are installed and reinstall didn't help. I really don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `software-properties-common` instead of `python-software-properties`. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/439566.

Answer (score 3):

The package name changed in the repository from `python-software-properties` to `python3-software-properties`. Install that and all be good!

Comment: Is this for only Python 3.x?